# using java's built in array-list to create heap application?

Tags: java, arraylist, heap

I made this application, though i made it by using java's built in array-list. Is it possible this is a heap still?

Cause it works

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0e5c609045b8edbffcadd25080b45f8

Comment: If this code works fine, you should submit it on our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: By the way, we don't follow links to code on this site.  Because links break.  And the question then becomes useless to others.

Comment: Look up binary heap on Wikipedia and it shows how to build using arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code. I don't think that it will be considered as Heap. Heap stores data like this structure

[image: See this image] .

This is how a heap node looks like

```
class hnode
{
int key;
hnode l;
hnode r;
hnode p;  // parent
// constructor
hnode(int x){ key=x; l=r=p=null; }
}
```

PreOrder

```
  public void preorder(hnode temp)
{
    if( temp!= null)
    {
        System.out.println(temp.key);
        preorder(temp.l);
        preorder(temp.r);

    }  
}
```

And main method

```
public class Heap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 maxheap obj= new maxheap();
 obj.insert(12);
 obj.insert(7);
 obj.insert(6);
 obj.insert(10);
 obj.insert(8);
 obj.insert(20);

 obj.preorder(obj.rroot());
}


}
```

Answer will be FOR MAX NODE

```
20
10
7
8
12
6
```

[image: Here is picture]